# declarationerror identifier not found or not unique onlyOwner

Tags: solidity, nft, royalties

I am getting this error at onlyOwner keyword `function setRoyaltyInfo(address _receiver, uint96 _royaltyFeesInBips) public onlyOwner { royaltyAddress = _receiver; royaltyFeesInBips = _royaltyFeesInBips; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you import Ownable.sol and inherit from the Ownable.sol contract ?

```
contract myContract is Ownable{
}
```

Comment: yes I forgot it. imported now and Thank you